# Upgrade Ebean on PlayFramework 2.2.2

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2, ebean

I have been having an ugly time with `Ebean` since I started using `Play Framework`, which I absolutely love otherwise.

Ebean has just fixed a bug that is affecting me, but it seems that the fix was not picked up during the last deployment of Play which was v2.2.2, which I have updated to.

Is is possible to manually upgrade Ebean in my instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to put this on your SBT

```
dependencyOverrides += "org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm-agent" % "3.2.2","org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "3.3.1-RC2"
```

Comment: Thank you, this put me on the right path. However, I had to add this:

    `"org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "3.3.1-RC2",
    "org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm-agent" % "3.2.2"`

Now it seems I have a new problem... After running `play idea` to regenerate my project, then `play`, then `run`, my project "boots" up, but I get the following compile error:

    `error: package play.db.ebean does not exist`

So I'm not out of the water yet. Am I missing a step?

Comment: try to keep the javaEbean there and see if it works. I've asked you to remove it, because it will download the dependencies of the play ebean wich will direct for the older version. Updated my answer and keep the javaEbean in SBT

Comment: I tried that before I saw your comments, and got more, deeper errors about missing internal classes. I think I could be SOL. It seems that the newest `Ebean` version is incompatible with `Play-2.2.2`.

Comment: which classes are missing?

Comment: I tried again, leaving `javaEbean` in place, and adding the same two lines I added in my above comment, ran `play idea`, the `play` then `run`, and now it seems to be up and running.

I'll accept your answer, but please update it to the two lines I sited, as the old `ebean` lib isn't used anymore, it's the newer `avaje-ebeanorm`.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: We brought up the issue with TypeSafe, and James Roper was nice enough to create a compatibility library.  Using that, we've been able to successfully use the 3.3.3 version of the Ebean library.

It's as simple as adding this to your Build.scala/sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "3.3.3",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-ebean-33-compat" % "1.0.0"
)
```

The compatibility library is here:
https://github.com/typesafehub/play-ebean-33-compat

ORIGINAL:
Late to the party, but I think this is currently not possible, since the Play Ebean Plugin in Play 2.2.3 is incompatible with the Ebean 3.3.x releases.

This issue exists against the Play Framework https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2672.  What I've found is that after subsequent recompiles (without cleaning), it will eventually compile and even work.  This may lead you to believe that this is not an issue at all.  This probably has to do with the older version of the Ebean library getting picked up eventually.